# Loading iframe (google map) stored in variable loaded from mysql into a div from link

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-maps

I have been trying ot hunt this down all afternoon, Im pretty new to all this and am building my first site with php

what Im trying to do is I have a google maps embed code stored in a Db which I have assigned to a variable $map, I want to inject the embed code into an existing div.

So basically a click here for map.  I may be way off on what I can do here.
Im sure there is a fancier way to do this but Im just learning and trying something simple.

Sorry if this is something that is obvious.

I have no code to show as i have murdered it and it is an unhelpful mess now.

Answer (score 0):

If the page has already been served to the user, you'll need to use javascript to update the div, or reload the page.  I jQuery's .post method to dynamically refresh divs with using AJAX.  Info at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code on my website, which sounds similar to what you're trying to do, but in my case, I'm passing the address to the embed code in the `$addresssubjectfullgoogle` variable:

```
<iframe width="100%"
        height="350"
        frameborder="1"
        scrolling="no"
        marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0" src="
        https://maps.google.com/?f=q&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;output=embed&amp;q=<?php echo $addresssubjectfullgoogle;?>&amp;z=18&amp;ll=<?php echo $addresssubjectfullgoogle;?>&amp;ie=UTF8">
</iframe>
```

I suspect that you could do something similar except that in your case, the same could might look something like this:

```
<iframe width="100%"
        height="350"
        frameborder="1"
        scrolling="no"
        marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0" src="<?php echo $map;?>">
</iframe>
```

I hope that's helpful.